# Skype Video Call Not Working Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, skype

Am having issue with Skype 2.2 (Beta), wherein am not able to make video calls on Ubuntu 11.10 64 bit.

Any solutions for having this issue fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe this video will help, it's on Greek but the capitations are on English, and there's summary in video description.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WeaLCzB4qy8