# Skype Video not working 13.04 & 13.10?

Tags: 13.04, video, skype, 13.10

I am trying to fix the issue with the video calls. I can check the video from the option menu, it works fine. But it does not work while calling someone. It shows video disabled. 
How can i fix this issue? I am using Ubuntu 13.10 and skype version 4.2.0.11

I checked all sites including below links but could not find solution:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/300060/skype-no-video-in-13-04 
[Skype Video Call Not Working Ubuntu 11.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/111801/skype-video-call-not-working-ubuntu-11-10)
[No video skype found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161208/no-video-skype-found)
[Video doesn't work well in skype](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35701/video-doesnt-work-well-in-skype)
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WeaLCzB4qy8

Answer (score 3):

Quelitu has had support for Skype webcam since 12.10...

The Ubuntu 13.10 upgrade creates other issues for Skype.

These commands from the Quelitu website do work.  They include the fix for 13.10 (`/usr/bin/env PULSE_LATENCY_MSEC=30`) and work in both launchers and terminals:

Skype without webcam:

```
bash -c '/usr/bin/env PULSE_LATENCY_MSEC=30 skype'
```

Skype with webcam:

```
bash -c 'LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so /usr/bin/env PULSE_LATENCY_MSEC=30 skype'
```

From Quelitu's page:
http://wavesofthefuture.net/computers/download-telecharger-descargas-free-gratuit-gratis-quelitu.shtml

Answer (score 0):

```
env PULSE_LATENCY_MSEC=30 bash -c 'LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so skype %U'
```

No need for path on environment variables